# Qt SDL blit(?) issue

Tags: qt, sdl, surface, blit

I'm using Qt and SDL to display surfaces on my application, I initialize the widget like said on [this page](http://irmatden.developpez.com/tutoriels/sdl/), I blit 2 or 3 surfaces on the window but the only result is a black screen. And when I close the app, the blitted images appears for 1 or 2 frames.

My code is long and I don't know witch part is the wrong one so I'll edit my post with lines you'll think useful to post instead of posting hundreds useless lines.

Comment: `like said in NeHe website` at least a link is required.

Comment: Done and it wasn't NeHe, glad you point that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, Qt was setting up a window behind SDL window and that's why I was able to see the SDL one just for a few ms.